# does not change color in the side menu header dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I need side menu so I have used side menu template in my project. I am trying to use dynamic colors in header. I have obtained the colors to change accordingly in the content but I need it to change in the header too. I tried without using side menu template. When I put ion-header in the same page where my contents are displayed, the header color changes but side menu does not work. Is there any mechanism to do this??

app controller

```
.state('sidemenu',{
        url:'/sidemenu',
        abstract:true,
        templateUrl:'templates/sidemenu.html'
      })


      //id is passed as the parameter
      .state('sidemenu.chapters',{
        url:'/chapters/:id',
        views:{
          'menuContent':{
            templateUrl:'templates/chapters.html',
            controller: 'ChaptersCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
```

In my ChaptersCtrl, I have the value required to change the color, but I can't use it in sidemenu.html.

sidemenu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
      <ion-nav-bar class="dark header header-height">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-dark button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close class="item item-icon-left" href="#/content">
          <i class="icon ion-bookmark"></i>
          Table of Content
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't understand, some code or plunker would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `$rootScope` and `ng-class`.

`$rootScope` works the same way as `$scope`, except the variable will be available through the whole application. You can use this to set the class name in a variable when you enter a certain page. Let's say `$rootScope.headClass = "mycustomclass"`.

After that, you can add the `ng-class` argument to your side-menu header. `ng-class` makes sure that your string is converted to a class. So you would add `ng-class = "{{headClass}}"`to your ion-header in the sidemenu.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but i couldnot use $rootScope and ng-class in my project since my sidemenu template is an abstract template.

Comment: Yes you can. You can use the ng-class in the html of your abstract template. And after this, $rootscope can be used from every controller, as this changes the scope of the whole application.

Comment: I have managed to get value, but i have no idea of using that value in css. Can u give a simple demo. I have "color : #808080", so i want it to use as a background color.

Comment: I tried doing like this since i found sass doesnot take dynamic variable.<ion-nav-bar ng-class="{0:'one', 1:'two',2:'three'}[id]"> but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's great, but I've done it like:

`if (counter == 10) {
  $rootScope.final = 'color:red;';
}`

`<button class="button button-counter">
      <span style="{{final}}">{{timer}}</span>
</button>`